Backup and restore metadata of PieCloudDB
I am using the cloud edition, and the overall usage of the database is relatively light, about 1GB. I want to know how to backup and restore the metadata of PieCloudDB Database management and control platform?

The process of logical backup and restore of PieCloudDB database cloud native platform is as follows:
Backup: You can export a logical backup of the "dbpiebackend" database using the pg_dump command：pg_dump -U [username] [databasename] > /file path
If you want to compress the exported file size, you can execute the compression command on the pipeline operation: pg_dump -U [username] [databasename] | gzip > filename.gz
Restore: Use the psql command to directly read the backed up files: psql --set ON_ERROR_STOP=on -U [username] [databasename] < /file path
